# Sitecore hosted on IIS, API returned 404 but has content

Tags: asp.net, api, iis, sitecore, http-status-code-404

I have a Sitecore site and I'm trying to make API calls from a controller. For some reason API always returns the 404 not found, but it also executes the code correctly and returns the content. I tried to call the same API endpoint via Postman and returned the 200 code with content.

Here's my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute("Feature.DataIntegration.Api", "api/dataintegration/{action}",
new
{
    controller = "DataIntegration"
});
```

Here's my API (I tried to use `[HttpGet]` attribute, but it didn't work):

```
public string test1()
{
    return "Asdas";
}
```

This is my RestSharp code:

```
var url = "http://tdev.xxx.cd.local/api/dataintegration/test1";
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest();
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This is Postman's return:
[image]

This is when the result from RestSharp (I also tried with httpclient, the same result):
[image]

I have tried to disable my firewall, but doesn't work neither.

How can I fix the 404 not found? If I don't fix this, does this affect the API once deployed to a real server?

Comment: I didn't see any 404 error when I test your code on my side. The response return isSuccessful=true all the time. So we need to figure out where is the 404 error returned. Please enable failed request tracing for your IIS 10 and post the detailed error message.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: thank you @JokiesDing, i will try to enable failed request tracing